# Automapper: Unable to map between a list and an model that derives from the list

Tags: c#, automapper

When I map an object that derives from a list, I receive an error

> Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method System.String 'get_Item(Int32)'

However, if I use the fix from [#3597](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3597), the mapper will run but the result is empty.

Source/destination types:

```
public class ListExtension : List<string>
{
}
```

Mapping configuration:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<ListExtension, List<string>>()
        .ForMember("Item", op => op.Ignore());
    cfg.CreateMap<List<string>, ListExtension>()
        .ForMember("Item", op => op.Ignore());
});

IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

**Expected behavior**

The list maps into the `ListExtension`, which derives from the same type as the list. In the reproduction example, I would expect the test to pass.

**Actual behavior**

When I map the list, I get this error

> Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method System.String get_Item(Int32)

However, I use the fix from #3597, the mapper will run but the result is empty. In the reproduction example, the test does not pass.

Steps to reproduce:

```
[Fact]
public void Issue1()
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<ListExtension, List<string>>()
            .ForMember("Item", op => op.Ignore());
        cfg.CreateMap<List<string>, ListExtension>()
            .ForMember("Item", op => op.Ignore());
    });

    IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

    List<string> myList = new List<string> { "0", "1", "2" };

    var afterMap = mapper.Map<ListExtension>(myList);
    Assert.Equal(myList.Count, afterMap.Count);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go with a slightly different approach of using a custom converter that implements the `AutoMapper.ITypeConverter<in TSource, TDestination>` generic interface to make the mapping configuration to work.

The converter class will need to expose a `TDestination Convert(TSource source, TDestination destination, ResolutionContext context)` method that contains the mapping logic

So for the example you posted, the changes will look like-

```
// class inheriting from List<string>
public class ListExtension : List<string>
{
}

// converter class containing mapping logic
public class ListToListExtensionConverter : ITypeConverter<List<string>, ListExtension>
{
    public ListExtension Convert(List<string> source, ListExtension destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (destination == null)
            destination = new ListExtension();

        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            destination.Add(item);
        }

        return destination;
    }
}

// mapper configuration that uses the converter logic
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<List<string>, ListExtension>().ConvertUsing<ListToListExtensionConverter>();
});
```

And eventually the method to test will look like-

```
[Fact]
public void Issue1()
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<List<string>, ListExtension>().ConvertUsing<ListToListExtensionConverter>();
    });

    IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

    List<string> myList = new List<string> { "0", "1", "2" };

    var afterMap = mapper.Map<ListExtension>(myList);
    Assert.Equal(myList.Count, afterMap.Count);

}
```

Comment: Tested and confirmed this solution does work. Thank you!
Alternatively, if you do not want to implement a custom converter, my work around was to ignore the "Item" property, then map them in the AfterMap. However, my AfterMap was practically the same logic as the custom converter. For code organization, a custom converter was cleaner.

Comment: You don't need a map here, you can just pass the constructed list to `Map`. And, of course, deriving from `List` is almost always a design error. Favour composition over inheritance.